# How to use yadcf with datatable using search date rage with 2 datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, yadcf

I use datatable and I want to search between date i've a data ex. 2018-2-3 to 2019-3-4
in my html

```
<div id="startfrom">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="From">
</div>
<div id="endto">
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="To">
</div>
```

In my js i use datatable with  yadcf

```
<script> 
    var table = $("#myTable").DataTable();
    yadcf.init(table , [{
        column_number: 9,
        filter_type: "date",
        datepicker_type: "bootstrap-datetimepicker",
        date_format: "yyyy/mm/dd"
    }]);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the range_date filter

In your HTML, put this

```
 <div >
   <label>Date Range</label><br>
   <span id="dateFilter"></span>
 </div>
```

And in your JS, put this

```
{
  column_number: 9,
  filter_container_id: 'dateFilter',
  filter_type: 'range_date'
}
```